# Laravel duplicate DB entry error page

Tags: forms, laravel, error-handling, model

I made a simple form, that saves data in a DB in Laravel 5.x with the the use of Forms package. 
One of the "elements" is unique, which I have made a rule that it must be unique. I made that in the migrations folder. When i run the site, the form works as it should. When you do not enter all the fields it refreshesh with all the data still inside. But when i input a duplicate (in the unique required filed) it does not refresh the site, but throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

Comment: You need to add a [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) check before saving.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that was actually the case. Thank you. Simple actually.